# why do I need background-size 200% instead of cover

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use an inline svg as a background-image (data url), but `background-size:cover` does not seems to work well, however with `200%` its fits perfectly.

I'd like to understand the issue so that I can make sure I have a consistent render with different browsers. Ideally I'd like to keep using `background-size:cover` if possible

```css
.card {
  display: inline-flex; /* required in my context */
  width: 45vmax;
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 2 2"><g fill="red"><path d="M0,1v-1h1z" opacity=".4" /><path d="M1,0v1h-1z" opacity=".2"/></g></svg>');
  background-size: cover;
}

._200percent {
  background-size: 200%;
}

.video {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="card">
  <div class="video"></div>
</a>
<a class="card _200percent">
  <div class="video"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Try changing your svg viewbox from `viewBox="0 0 2 2"` to `viewBox="0 0 1 1"`, does this solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented you can adjust the viewbox to cover the path and avoid having extra spaces and the use of `200%`

```css
svg {
  border:1px solid;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 2 2"><g fill="red"><path d="M0,1v-1h1z" opacity=".4" /><path d="M1,0v1h-1z" opacity=".2"/></g></svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1 1"><g fill="red"><path d="M0,1v-1h1z" opacity=".4" /><path d="M1,0v1h-1z" opacity=".2"/></g></svg>
```

You can also do this using CSS and gradient without the need of SVG

```css
.card {
  display: inline-flex; /* required in my context */
  width: 45vmax;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(255,0,0,0.4) 49.5%,rgba(255,0,0,0.2) 50%),
    lightblue;
}

.video {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="card">
  <div class="video"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: You forgot to say why the `viewBox` needs to be changed. :)   It is because OPs paths are only 1x1 units in size.  The viewBox of 2x2 is two times larger than it needs to be.  Hence the 200%.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau true, I thought it was clear with my first snippet that the second one is twice bigger than the first and already covering the whole area unlike the first one where we need the 200% to cover the spaces.

Comment: Aw, my mistake while coding the svg I think ! thanks a lot